# SqlServer Rand() question

Tags: sql-server, random

I am writing a procedure where each call it needs to get a single random number.  This procedure is called from our .net web service.

I tried implementing this using rand().  However, when I have multiple calls to the stored procedure within milliseconds, I am getting a lot of collisions in that the same random number is being generated.  If there is a space of about 20 or 30 ms between subsequent calls it appears to work ok.

It appears that rand() is reseeded each stored procedure call by SqlServer.  From what I understand this is a problem because one should seed a random number generator once and that one doesn't get a good sequence of pseudo-random numbers if one is reseeding each call to rand. Also, it appears that calls to the same sp that are within 1 or 2 milliseconds get seeded with the same value.

Here is the statement itself in the stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @randomNumber char(9)

SET @randomNumber = RIGHT('00000' + CAST(CAST(rand()*100000 AS INT) AS VARCHAR(5)),5)
+ RIGHT('00000' + CAST(CAST(rand()*10000 AS INT) AS VARCHAR(4)),4)
```

Does anyone have a suggestion for fixing this?

Will I have to write my own random number generator that is seeded once and saves its state in a table across calls?  How does SQL Server seed rand()?  Is it truly random or if you call an sp within 1 or 2 milliseconds of each other on separate connections will it be seeded with the same seed causing a collision?

Comment: Have you tried to write a CLR stored procedure and use the random number ability of the .NET framework?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2008, then you can use the CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM() function.  This will randomize data for every row even if you were trying to calculate millions of random numbers in one query execution and doesn't have any seeding issues:

```
SELECT CAST(RIGHT(CAST(CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1) AS INT) AS VARCHAR(100)), 1) AS INT)
```

Here's the link to the BOL article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627408.aspx

Answer (score 5):

In your example, replace `rand()*10000` with `ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 9999`

However, for char(9):

```
SELECT RIGHT('000000000' + CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 999999999) AS char(9), 9)
```

To seed RAND *randomly*...

```
RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))
```

Edit:

Note, RAND is badly implemented in SQL Server. Don't use it.

Comment: +! Works, though I wonder if there is any guarantee about the distribution of newid() or checksum(newid()).  Wasn't the MAC address used in the calculation of newid()?

Comment: newid = GUID, so same statistics. CHECKSUM = signed 32 bit = 4 billion.

Comment: Seems like the best solution, so far.  Although, I am also looking into a clr stored procedure that uses RNGCryptoServiceProvider.

Comment: @Jeff: I answered about RNGCryptoServiceProvider in SQL here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521835/how-to-generate-a-rngcryptoserviceprovider-like-number-in-tsql/1521929#1521929

Answer (score 0):

The [RAND() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx) has an optional seed parameter that you could use for this.  If you pass the last generated random value as a seed to the next call to rand(), you are guaranteed to get a new random number.

Thanks to gbn for pointing out that the seed is an integer, while rand() returns a float.  With that knowledge, here's a working example!  First create a table:

```
create table RandomNumber (number float)
insert into RandomNumber values (rand())
```

Then grab a random number and store the new number in a transaction:

```
declare @new float
begin transaction
select @new = rand(-2147483648 + 4294967295 * number)
    from RandomNumber with (updlock, holdlock)
update RandomNumber set number = @new
commit transaction
print 'Next bingo number is: ' + cast(cast(@new*100 as int) as varchar)
```

An SQL Server integer varies between -2147483648 and 2147483647, and a random number is a float between 0.0 and 1.0.  So `-2147483648 + 4294967295 * number` should cover the full range of available integers.

The transaction ensures that only one connection at a time reads and stores a new number.  So the numbers are random even on different connections to SQL Server.  (By the way, I voted for gbn's answer, seems much easier.)

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but then I would have to save this state, in a table and look it up for each call in the sp.  Seems expensive.  Also, will this produce a good pseudo-random sequence of numbers if I set the seed in this manner?

Comment: @Andomar: RAND takes an int seed, so you are seeding the same for each itertion. See an old answer of mine here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038681/sql-random-number-not-working/1354125#1354125

Answer (score 0):

You could use a table with just an identifier field for creating unique nunbers to use as seed:

```
declare
  @randomNumber char(9),
  @seed1 int,
  @seed2 int

insert into SeedTable () values ()
set @seed1 = scope_identity()

insert into SeedTable () values ()
set @seed2 = scope_identity()

set @randomNumber = right('00000' + 
    cast(cast(rand(@seed1) * 100000 as int) as varchar(5)), 5) +
    right('00000' + 
    cast(cast(rand(@seed2) * 10000 as int) as varchar(4)), 4)

if (@seed2 > 10000) truncate table SeedTable
```

Comment: Did you intend to create a table called SeedTable?

Comment: @Andomar: Yes, that's the table with just an identifier that I was talking about.

Comment: @Guffy: and truncate table resets identity columns?

Comment: @Andomar: Yes, it does. If you want the identity to continue you could use a delete to keep the size down instead.