# How to update each row of a table with a random row from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, random, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm building my first de-identification script, and running into issues with my approach.

I have a table `dbo.pseudonyms` whose `firstname` column is populated with 200 rows of data.  Every row in this column of 200 rows has a value (none are null).  This table also has an `id` column (int, primary key, not null) with the numbers 1-200.

What I want to do is, in one statement, re-populate my entire `USERS` table with `firstname` data randomly selected for each row from my `pseudonyms` table.

To generate the random number for picking I'm using `ABS(Checksum(NewId())) % 200`.  Every time I do `SELECT ABS(Checksum(NewId())) % 200` I get a numeric value in the range I'm looking for just fine, no intermittently erratic behavior.

HOWEVER, when I use this formula in the following statement:

```
SELECT pn.firstname 
FROM DeIdentificationData.dbo.pseudonyms pn 
WHERE pn.id = ABS(Checksum(NewId())) % 200
```

I get VERY intermittent results.  I'd say about 30% of the results return one name picked out of the table (this is the expected result),  about 30% come back with *more than one* result (which is baffling, there are no duplicate `id` column values), and about 30% come back with NULL (even though there are *no* empty rows in the `firstname` column)

I did look for quite a while for this specific issue, but to no avail so far.  I'm *assuming* the issue has to do with using this formula as a pointer, but I'd be at a loss how to do this otherwise.

Thoughts?

Comment: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. If you are using SQL Server you might want to consider [`CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627408.aspx). [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657474/sqlserver-rand-question/1657672#1657672).

Comment: `ABS(Checksum(NewId()))` is re-evaluated per row. You probably want `rand` which isn't.

Comment: I like crypt_gen_random, good find.  However i'm not sure how I'd limit my random number range to between 1 - 200?

Comment: That is reevaluated per row as well.

Comment: Martin what I am trying to get is a new random value for every row I pull and update my USER table with.   If the formula is not re-evaluated per row, would that mean I'd be setting every row with the same value?

Comment: Yes it would. The  `SELECT pn.firstname FROM DeIdentificationData.dbo.pseudonyms pn WHERE pn.id = ABS(Checksum(NewId())) % 200` in isolation won't work either though as it is evaluated for each row in pseudonyms. So you need a random value reevaluated for each row in the outer query that is then static for the inner query. There probably isn't a guaranteed way of getting that. SQL server doesn't guarantee where it will evaluate compute scalars.

Comment: Am I using an entirely incorrect approach to achieve what I want, then?  C# perhaps?

Comment: So, you have 200 `Pseudonyms`. How many `Users` do you have?

Comment: I edited the title of the question. I think it better reflects what you are after now. Please edit it further if necessary.

Comment: @MartinSmith, regarding your comment about (non-)guarantees where SQL Server evaluates compute scalar. Could you have a look at my answer, please? I believe it will always work as expected, i.e. it doesn't rely on some undefined behavior. I would appreciate it if you could point out any problems. Thank you.

Comment: Vladimir, I currently have a user table count of 6096.

Comment: @user1910915, OK, with 6000 Users and 200 Pseudonyms you will have the same Pseudonym used several times. In my answer I generate 1000 users, so it correctly models your situation.

Answer (score 1):

**Why your query in the question returns unexpected results**

Your original query selects from `Pseudonyms`. Server scans through each row of the table, picks the `ID` from that row, generates a random number, compares the generated number to the `ID`.

When by chance the generated number for particular row happen to be the same as `ID` of that row, this row is returned in the result set. It is quite possible that by chance generated number would never be the same as `ID`, as well as that generated number coincided with `ID` several times.

A bit more detailed:

- Server picks a row with `ID=1`.
- Generates a random number, say `25`. Why not? A decent random number.
- Is `1 = 25` ? No => This row is not returned.
- Server picks a row with `ID=2`.
- Generates a random number, say `125`. Why not? A decent random number.
- Is `2 = 125` ? No => This row is not returned.
- And so on...

---

**[Here is a complete solution on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2bdd3/9/1)**

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @VarPseudonyms TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), PseudonymName varchar(50) NOT NULL);
DECLARE @VarUsers TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), UserName varchar(50) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @VarUsers (UserName)
SELECT TOP(1000)
    'UserName' AS UserName
FROM sys.all_objects
ORDER BY sys.all_objects.object_id;

INSERT INTO @VarPseudonyms (PseudonymName)
SELECT TOP(200)
    'PseudonymName'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sys.all_objects.object_id) AS varchar) AS PseudonymName
FROM sys.all_objects
ORDER BY sys.all_objects.object_id;
```

Table `Users` has 1000 rows with the same `UserName` for each row. Table `Pseudonyms` has 200 rows with different `PseudonymNames`:

```
SELECT * FROM @VarUsers;
ID   UserName
--   --------
1    UserName
2    UserName
...
999  UserName
1000 UserName

SELECT * FROM @VarPseudonyms;
ID   PseudonymName
--   -------------
1    PseudonymName1
2    PseudonymName2
...
199  PseudonymName199
200  PseudonymName200
```

**First attempt**

At first I tried a direct approach. For each row in `Users` I want to get one random row from `Pseudonyms`:

```
SELECT
    U.ID
    ,U.UserName
    ,CA.PseudonymName
FROM
    @VarUsers AS U
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1)
            P.PseudonymName
        FROM @VarPseudonyms AS P
        ORDER BY CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)
    ) AS CA
;
```

It turns out that optimizer is too smart and this produced some random, but the same `PseudonymName` for each `User`, which is not what I expected:

```
ID   UserName   PseudonymName
1    UserName   PseudonymName181
2    UserName   PseudonymName181
...
999  UserName   PseudonymName181
1000 UserName   PseudonymName181
```

So, I tweaked this approach a bit and generated a random number for each row in `Users` first. Then I used the generated number to find the `Pseudonym` with this `ID` for each row in `Users` using `CROSS APPLY`.

`CTE_Users` has an extra column with random number from 1 to 200. In `CTE_Joined` we pick a row from `Pseudonyms` for each `User`.
Finally we `UPDATE` the original `Users` table.

**Final solution**

```
WITH
CTE_Users
AS
(
    SELECT
        U.ID
        ,U.UserName
        ,1 + 200 * (CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4) as int) / 4294967295.0 + 0.5) AS rnd
    FROM @VarUsers AS U
)
,CTE_Joined
AS
(
    SELECT
        CTE_Users.ID
        ,CTE_Users.UserName
        ,CA.PseudonymName
    FROM
        CTE_Users
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT P.PseudonymName
            FROM @VarPseudonyms AS P
            WHERE P.ID = CAST(CTE_Users.rnd AS int)
        ) AS CA
)
UPDATE CTE_Joined
SET UserName = PseudonymName;
```

**Results**

```
SELECT * FROM @VarUsers;
ID   UserName
1    PseudonymName41
2    PseudonymName132
3    PseudonymName177
...
998  PseudonymName60
999  PseudonymName141
1000 PseudonymName157
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2bdd3/9/1)**

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach:

```
UPDATE u
SET u.FirstName = p.Name
FROM Users u
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP(1) p.Name
    FROM pseudonyms p
    WHERE u.Id IS NOT NULL -- must be some unique identifier on Users
    ORDER BY NEWID()
) p
```

Full example from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36185100/6620329

Answer (score 0):

Update a random Users id into UpdatedBy column of Table01

```
UPDATE a 
SET a.UpdatedBy=b.id
FROM [dbo].[Table01] a
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      id,
      ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by 1 order by NEWID()) RN
    FROM Users b
    WHERE a.id != b.id
) b 
WHERE RN = 1
```