# Updating a SQL Server table with random names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying the following:

```
update [Employees] set Last_User = 

(select top 1 name from 
(select 'John' as name 
union select 'Tim' as name
union select 'Jane' as name
union select 'Jack' as name
union select 'Steve' as name
union select 'Ann' as name
) 

as names order by newid())
```

but keep getting the same name for all rows. how can I make it vary?

Note: names are entered in query and do not come from another table.

Thanks

Comment: you do  `update Employees = 'name that is randomly picked` it means all employees get that random name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update each row of a table with a random row from another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760225/how-to-update-each-row-of-a-table-with-a-random-row-from-another-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to update the whole column instead of updating each row, hence the first value which is getting generated is updated to all the rows, you can do the intended task by using T-SQL

```
DECLARE @counter int = 1

WHILE @counter <= (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [Employees]) --or any speific row set you want to modify
BEGIN

UPDATE a
 set Last_User = 
(SELECT top 1 name from 
(SELECT 'John' as name 
UNION SELECT 'Tim' AS name
UNION SELECT 'Jane' AS name
UNION SELECT 'Jack' AS name
UNION SELECT 'Steve' AS name
UNION SELECT 'Ann' AS name
) 

AS names ORDER BY NEWID())
 FROM (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Last_User)rnum FROM [Employees])a
WHERE a.rnum = @counter

SET @counter = @counter + 1

END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach:

```
declare  @Employees table (last_user nvarchar(100))
insert @Employees values('a')
insert @Employees values('b')
insert @Employees values('c')

declare @temp table(name nvarchar(100))
insert into @temp values('John')
insert into @temp values('Tim')
insert into @temp values('Jane')
insert into @temp values('Jack')
insert into @temp values('Steve')
insert into @temp values('Ann')

update @Employees set Last_User = 

(select top 1 name from 
    @temp as names order by newid())

select * from @Employees
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am a little confused. Where is my table name? and what is a, b, c?

Comment: Hi SJJohnson, I'm using a temporary table [@Employees] instead  [Employees] table, because I just want to show how we can solve this task. You can simple replate [@Employees]  by your table. About 'a','b','c' are sample data.

Comment: I tried both suggestions. The one by prenesh u gave random values for each row. This solution (by Edward N) did not. Instead it gave the same value for all the rows. My algorithm situation was slightly different so I can't say if that was the problem, HOWEVER this uses an UPDATE, which I think is for a column, but the algorithm by prenesh actually treats each row seperately.