# Set field to random value from another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
update table1
set firstname = (select top 1 firstname from table2 order by NEWID())
```

This just sets table1.firstname to the same value for all records. I know it's possible to do this, but everything I've seen online expects the same row count in both tables (or at least a greater amount in table1). I have 200,000 records in table1, I have 200 in table2. How can I set table1.firstname to a random value from table2.firstname when the row counts are off?

Comment: does table1 has a primary key?

Comment: your right side expression is evaluated only once,you will need to look a way to correlate it like devarts answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (a INT)
DECLARE @t2 TABLE (b INT, c INT)

INSERT INTO @t1(a)
VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)

INSERT INTO @t2(b)
VALUES (0), (1), (2)

UPDATE t2
SET c = t1.a
FROM @t2 t2
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP(1) t1.a
    FROM @t1 t1
    WHERE t2.b IS NOT NULL -- any calculations for t2 columns
    ORDER BY NEWID()
) t1

SELECT * FROM @t2
```

Output -

```
b           c
----------- -----------
0           5
1           1
2           0
```

Comment: from my test, you can't just use any column for this filter: `WHERE t2.b IS NOT NULL`, it must be on a unique one

Comment: @Lamak I think he can use `ROW_NUMBER` in case such a field does not exist.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos sure, I'm just pointing an issue so op is aware of it before running this query

Comment: This worked, thanks. @Lamak, I did have a unique field to use for t2.b.